# replace string with usable chars (slugify)

Tags: php

I want to use this code to convert the string "müller" to "muller".

```
$test = "müller";

function slugify($str) {
 $search = array("Á", "À", "Â", "Ä", "Ă", "Ā", "Ã", "Å", "Ą", "Æ", "Ć", "Ċ", "Ĉ", "Č", "Ç", "Ď", "Đ", "Ð", "É", "È", "Ė", "Ê", "Ë", "Ě", "Ē", "Ę", "Ə", "Ġ", "Ĝ", "Ğ", "Ģ", "á", "à", "â", "ä", "ă", "ā", "ã", "å", "ą", "æ", "ć", "ċ", "ĉ", "č", "ç", "ď", "đ", "ð", "é", "è", "ė", "ê", "ë", "ě", "ē", "ę", "ə", "ġ", "ĝ", "ğ", "ģ", "Ĥ", "Ħ", "I", "Í", "Ì", "İ", "Î", "Ï", "Ī", "Į", "Ĳ", "Ĵ", "Ķ", "Ļ", "Ł", "Ń", "Ň", "Ñ", "Ņ", "Ó", "Ò", "Ô", "Ö", "Õ", "Ő", "Ø", "Ơ", "Œ", "ĥ", "ħ", "ı", "í", "ì", "i", "î", "ï", "ī", "į", "ĳ", "ĵ", "ķ", "ļ", "ł", "ń", "ň", "ñ", "ņ", "ó", "ò", "ô", "ö", "õ", "ő", "ø", "ơ", "œ", "Ŕ", "Ř", "Ś", "Ŝ", "Š", "Ş", "Ť", "Ţ", "Þ", "Ú", "Ù", "Û", "Ü", "Ŭ", "Ū", "Ů", "Ų", "Ű", "Ư", "Ŵ", "Ý", "Ŷ", "Ÿ", "Ź", "Ż", "Ž", "ŕ", "ř", "ś", "ŝ", "š", "ş", "ß", "ť", "ţ", "þ", "ú", "ù", "û", "ü", "ŭ", "ū", "ů", "ų", "ű", "ư", "ŵ", "ý", "ŷ", "ÿ", "ź", "ż", "ž");
 $replace = array("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "AE", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "E", "G", "G", "G", "G", "G", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "ae", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "g", "g", "g", "g", "g", "H", "H", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "IJ", "J", "K", "L", "L", "N", "N", "N", "N", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "O", "CE", "h", "h", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "i", "ij", "j", "k", "l", "l", "n", "n", "n", "n", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "o", "R", "R", "S", "S", "S", "S", "T", "T", "T", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "U", "W", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Z", "Z", "Z", "r", "r", "s", "s", "s", "ss", "B", "t", "t", "b", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "u", "w", "y", "y", "y", "z", "z", "z");

$str = str_ireplace($search, $replace, strtolower(trim($str)));
$str = preg_replace('/[^\w\d\-\ ]/', '', $str);
$str = str_replace(' ', '-', $str);
return preg_replace('/\-{2,}', '-', $str);
}

slugify($test);
```

but the problem is, that the variable $test echos's still "müller".

Comment: Look into [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) instead of fiddling with it yourself.

Comment: You're missing the ending delimiter in `preg_replace()`. Also, you're not echoing the results, you should use `echo slugify($test);` if you want to echo the results. It should [work](https://eval.in/54328) fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thank's to **@Peehaa**!

this solution with iconv is working great:

```
$test = "müller";
$test = iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $test);
```

Answer (score 2):

try 
     str_replace("Á", "A");
     str_replace("À", "A");
etc..

Comment: or $str = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $str);